# Show image in jersey ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I trying to write custom exception mapper for CompletionException and to show image in case of this excption. This is my mapper:

```
@Provider
public class CustomCompleteExceptionManager implements ExceptionMapper<CompletionException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(CompletionException e) {
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(Paths.get("error.png").toFile())
                .type("image/img")
                .build();
    }
```

Method toResponse is called when my code throws `CompletionException`, but browser doesn't displays `error.png`. I get an error:

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://localhost:8080/cf/point might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

When I write just String message to `Response` it works fine:

```
@Provider
public class CustomCompleteExceptionManager implements ExceptionMapper<CompletionException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(CompletionException e) {
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(e.getMessage())
                .build();
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media type set in response is wrong.
It should be `.type("image/png")` not `image/img`.

This is the code when I tested in my local.

```
return Response
            .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity(Paths.get("/home","kishore","Pictures","Meme.png").toFile())
            .type("image/png")
            .build();
```